# Jcrop check the original image dimensions before preview

Tags: jquery, jcrop

How to determine the dimensions of the image before initializing preview and start cropping image only if the image width is more than 200px?

Here the original JS:

```
$('#my_file').on('change', function() {
    var file_name = $(this).val();
    if(file_name.length > 0) {
      addJcrop(this);
    }
});

var addJcrop = function(input) {
    if ($('#image_prev').data('Jcrop')) {
      $('#image_prev').data('Jcrop').destroy();
    }

    // this will add the src in image_prev as uploaded
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        $("#image_prev").attr('src', e.target.result);
        var box_width = $('#form-photo').width();
        $('#image_prev').Jcrop({
          setSelect: [ 175, 100, 400, 300 ],
          aspectRatio: 1,
          keySupport: false,
          boxWidth: box_width
          },function(){
          var jcrop_api = this;
          thumbnail = this.initComponent('Thumbnailer', { width: 326, height: 326 });
        });
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Clean Example Here: https://jsfiddle.net/5dykm7qc/23/

Answer (score 0):

Ok if i understand correctly you want to check the image dimensions before initiating cropping.

First of all, let me say im not an experienced coder so forgive me if this is wrong!

You need to create a new Image to check the dimensions like so.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#my_file').on('change', function(){
       reader = new FileReader();
       file = document.getElementById('my_file').files[0]
       if (file.type.match('image/*')) {
         reader.readAsDataURL(file);
         reader.onload = function(e) {
           image = new Image();
           image.src = e.target.result;
           image.onload = function() {
             if (image.width > 200) {
               $("#image-prev").Jcrop({
                 * add options *
               });
             } 
           }
         }
       }
     });
   });
```